# Cannot import namedtuple

Tags: python-3.x, importerror

I am currently working in PYCHARM and it  gives me the error whenever I run the program. I tried various methods to remove this error but to no avail.

What can I do to fix this issue?

```
import re
File "F:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\re.py", line 125, in <module>
import functools
File "F:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: cannot import name 'namedtuple'
```

Comment: Please provide the code snippet or code which you tried to help community to solve it.

Comment: @Rishab there is no error in the main code but if you are asking for the specific area then from collections import namedtuple is the issue

Answer (score 1):

Check the module in [stdlib named types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html), it gets imported instead.

You can either rename your module, or switch to absolute imports.

Hope this will help you.